# Computing eigen values and eigen vectors using PCACompute2

Tags: python, opencv, pca

Im using the following code to compute eigen vectors together with eigen values.

```
mean, eigenvectors, eigenvalues = cv2.PCACompute2(data_pts, mean)
```

but why am i getting the following error?

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'PCACompute2'

I have installed `opencv-contrib-python`  though using pip but still the error persists.
Is there any ways to find eigen values apart from PCACompute2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [numpy.linalg.eig](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) is what you're looking for? Assuming you're sending your input as a square matrix.

```
import numpy as np
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(M)
```

You may also want to take a look at an answer to this question:  [Do non-square matrices have eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/583953/320116) .

Comment: The input is an image of any dimension. it isnt always a square matrix

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the `contrib` package

```
sudo -H pip install opencv-contrib-python
sudo -H pip install opencv-python
```